# Are there macros that behave like \pdfximage and \pdflastximagepages but can be compiled with XeLaTeX?

Tags: macros, pdf

The following code can be compiled with `pdflatex` but not `xelatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,multido}
\begin{document}
\pdfximage{something.pdf}
\multido{\i=1+1}{\the\pdflastximagepages}{%
    \fbox{\includegraphics[page=\i,scale=0.25]{something}}
    \endgraf
}
\end{document}
```

The idea is to include each page of `something.pdf` as a separate image. I don't want to use `pdfpages` package and I want to use `xelatex`.

Are there macros that behave like `\pdfximage` and `\pdflastximagepages` but can be compiled with XeLaTeX?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `pdfpages`?

Comment: @egreg: Because I want to make each page as a separate image that might be put in `figure` environment for example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use

```
\edef\numberofpages{\the\XeTeXpdfpagecount something.pdf }
```

and then `\numberofpages` will expand to the number of pages of the file.

You can also use the same syntax as with pdfTeX by

```
\usepackage{ifxetex}

\ifxetex
  \newcount\pdflastximagepages
  \def\pdfximage#1{\pdflastximagepages=\XeTeXpdfpagecount"#1"\relax}
\fi
```

but of course you won't have the complete functionality of `\pdfximage` with XeTeX.

Comment: Your last update was actually the answer of my next question that I want to post. :-) Thanks.