# Long multi-page table with even-odd page splitting

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx, ltablex

I am a complete newbie at LaTeX and I would like to reproduce the following (exemplary) layout:
[image]

**The key requirements are:**

1. The table must span multiple pages vertically;
2. The table must be split on even/odd pages in landscape layout, so that each other page would continue the table horizontally, and each pair of pages would continue the table vertically;
3. The headers must be repeated.

I am aware of multiple packages that deal with tables (`longtable`, `tabularx`, `ltablex`), but I am having difficulties even choosing the environment, let alone make that layout happen using the documentation.

**Edit:** The actual data looks like this – column A is the width of the longest element, and there are several more columns to come:
[image]

Comment: Paracol can handle the left-right splitting, but will not necessarily align the two halves.  What you might do is create the table in a separate document with a wider text area and copy/split the resulting PDF.

Comment: @JohnKormylo sounds interesting, but I am not sure I understand the last part. What do you mean by “wider text area”?

Comment: If the screenshot shows a table with contents similar to your planned table, you could probably even be able to squeeze all columns onto one page, in which case a regular `longtable` would work perfectly fine. This however depends largely on the table's contents as well as on the length of the column headers and the first column.

Comment: @leandriis unfortunately I tried, but there is no way to make it work with any reasonable layout. I did consider manually splitting the data and generating separate tables, but wanted to keep it in LaTeX.

Comment: @MrVocabulary: Would you mind preparing a small example document containing an example table with contents close to the contents of your actual table? Probably there is nevertheless a way to present this information without splitting the table.

Comment: @leandriis I have edited the answer.

Comment: Use geometry to create a document with no margins and set \paperwidth to twice you current \textwidth and \paperheight to the current \textheight (print \the\textwidth  and \the\textheight to find out).

Comment: @JohnKormylu I will give it a try, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [John Kormylo's suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/578679/long-multi-page-table-with-even-odd-page-splitting#comment1456443_578679)  of creating the table in a separate document of appropriate size and later on including it in the main document, here is a first rough approach:

The following MWE is used to create the table. The values for `paperheight`  and `paperwidth` are equal to `textheight` and `2*textwidth`, respectively, of the document, in which you want to add the table (You can use `\the\textheight` and `\the\textwidth` to get the corresponding values.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0pt, paperheight=556.47656pt, paperwidth=860.00924pt]{geometry}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{makecell,rotating}

\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand{\cm}{\cellcolor{green!50!white}\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xm}{\cellcolor{red!50!white}\ding{55}}%

\begin{document}
\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\settowidth\rotheadsize{\theadfont other text}
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{r*{50}{c}}
           & \rothead{text} & \rothead{text} & \rothead{text} & \rothead{text} & \rothead{text} & \rothead{text} & \rothead{text} & \rothead{text} & \rothead{text} & \rothead{text} & \rothead{more text} & \rothead{text} & \rothead{text} & \rothead{text} & \rothead{text} & \rothead{text} & \rothead{text} & \rothead{text} & \rothead{text} & \rothead{text} & \rothead{text} & \rothead{text} & \rothead{text} & \rothead{text} & \rothead{text} & \rothead{text} & \rothead{text} & \rothead{other text} & \rothead{text} & \rothead{text} & \rothead{text} & \rothead{text} & \rothead{text} & \rothead{text} & \rothead{text} & \rothead{text} & \rothead{text} & \rothead{text} & \rothead{text} & \rothead{text} & \rothead{text} & \rothead{text} & \rothead{text} & \rothead{text} & \rothead{text} & \rothead{text} & \rothead{text} & \rothead{text} & \rothead{text} & \rothead{text} \\\endhead
short text 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm  \\
a bit longer text 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm  \\
word 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm  \\
short text 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm  \\
a bit longer text 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm  \\
word 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm  \\
short text 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm  \\
a bit longer text 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm  \\
word 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm  \\
short text 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm  \\
a bit longer text 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm  \\
word 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm  \\
short text 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm  \\
a bit longer text 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm  \\
word 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm  \\
short text 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm  \\
a bit longer text 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm  \\
word 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm  \\
short text 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm  \\
a bit longer text 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm  \\
word 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm  \\
short text 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm  \\
a bit longer text 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm  \\
word 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm  \\
short text 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm  \\
a bit longer text 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm  \\
word 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm  \\
short text 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm  \\
a bit longer text 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm  \\
word 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm  \\
short text 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm  \\
a bit longer text 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm  \\
word 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm  \\
short text 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm  \\
a bit longer text 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm  \\
word 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm  \\
short text 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm  \\
a bit longer text 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm  \\
word 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm  \\
short text 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm  \\
a bit longer text 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm  \\
word 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm  \\
short text 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm  \\
a bit longer text 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm  \\
word 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm  \\
short text 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm  \\
a bit longer text 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm  \\
word 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm  \\
short text 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm  \\
a bit longer text 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm  \\
word 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm  \\
short text 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm  \\
a bit longer text 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm  \\
word 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm  \\
short text 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm  \\
a bit longer text 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm  \\
word 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm  \\
short text 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm  \\
a bit longer text 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm  \\
word 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm  \\
short text 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm  \\
a bit longer text 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm  \\
word 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm  \\
short text 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm  \\
a bit longer text 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm  \\
word 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm  \\
short text 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm  \\
a bit longer text 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm  \\
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

This is how the resulting pdf file (named mylongtable.pdf in this particular case) looks like:

[image]

To automatically include the table into the actual document, I have written the macro `\includemytable` which automatically crops the right half of the image and inserts the remaining left half, then crops the left half and inserts the remaining right half. With the help of [Heiko Oberdiek's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125212/134144), the macro iterates over all pages present in the file mylongtable.pdf. You can adjust the file name using `\renewcommand{\mytablename}{<your file name here>}`.
To make sure, the table starts on a left (even) page, I used `\cleartoleftpage` [originally defined by Martin Scharrer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11709/134144).

This is the resulting MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand*\cleartoleftpage{%
  \clearpage
  \ifodd\value{page}\hbox{}\newpage\fi
} % from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11709/134144

\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcounter{pdfpages}
\newcommand*{\getpdfpages}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \sbox0{% 
      \includegraphics{#1}%
      \setcounter{pdfpages}{\pdflastximagepages}%
    }%
  \endgroup
} % from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125212/134144


\newcommand{\mytablename}{}

\renewcommand{\mytablename}{mylongtable}
\newcommand{\includemytable}{%
                                \getpdfpages{\mytablename.pdf}
                                \foreach \x in {1,...,\value{pdfpages}} {
                                \noindent%
                                \includegraphics[trim=0pt 0pt \the\textwidth pt 0pt, clip,  page=\x]{\mytablename}%
                                \par%
                                \noindent%
                                \includegraphics[trim=\the\textwidth pt 0pt 0pt 0pt, clip, page=\x]{\mytablename}%
                                \par}}
                                
\begin{document}

\lipsum
\lipsum[1-5]

\cleartoleftpage
\includemytable
\lipsum   
\end{document}
```

and its output:

[image]

---

Warning: With the current approach, the table is cut right in the middle. Depending on the column widths it can thus happen that the table is cut in the middle of a column. To overcome this, one would have to adjust the column widths to make sure the middle of the table is exactly between two adjacent columns. I did not (yet) address this issue in my answer!

Comment: to avoid problems with the cutting add some space between two columns with @{\hspace{1cm}}. (And yes, one has to do some careful calculations of the column widths in such a setup).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer could you explain a bit more where that should be defined? Within the macro itself?

Comment: @leandris thanks for your answer. I have copied your code 1:1 to table_file.tex and to main_file.tex. I have provided `table_file` in the second one as reference. However, while table_file compiles perfectly, I get errors in main_file: `Undefined control sequence. \includemytable` and `Missing number, treated as zero. \includemytable` for line 43. Where does it come from?

Comment: Which compiller did you use to compile the `main_file.tex`? Compiling with PDFLaTeX should work.

Comment: @leandriis I was using xelatex for the entirety of my project, but PDFLaTeX did indeed work. Do you know what might cause the issue?

Comment: [Heiko Oberdiek mentions in his anwer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125212/134144) from which I took the code to iterate over all pages of the pdf file, that `\pdflastximagepages` in only available when using PDFLaTeX. For XeLaTeX, [Are there macros that behave like \pdfximage and \pdflastximagepages but can be compiled with XeLaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47869/134144) might be interesting.

Comment: To make the code compilable with XeLaTeX, replace `\getpdfpages{\mytablename.pdf}` with `\edef\numberofpages{\the\XeTeXpdfpagecount \mytablename.pdf }` and `\foreach \x in {1,...,\value{pdfpages}} {` with `\foreach \x in {1,...,\numberofpages} {\numberofpages`.

Comment: @leandriis that worked like charm! Now I have to figure out how to adjust the details of formatting, but you have earned your bounty. Thank you!

Comment: @leandriis could you tell me how can I verically center text in my cells? I have tried `\begin{xltabular}[m]{\textwidth}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X r*{49}{c}}` which worked in clean `\begin{xltabular}[m]{0.75\linewidth}{@{} lX @{}}` example in another file, but doesn't seem to have a desired effect here (neither do most of the results). Is this possible it stems from something else in the example you made?

Comment: Adding `\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}` to the preamble in combination with `\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X*{50}{c}}` should help in order to vertically center the contents of each row.

Comment: @leandriis okay, last question (unless I can hire you): is it possible to force specific width to the first column (or two) here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118618/discussion-between-mrvocabulary-and-leandriis).